# How to append two DataFrames with different number of rows, populating the shorter one

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1], 'var4': ['P']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var2': list('abcd'), 'var3': range(4)})
```

With the above data frames I'd like to join them with populating the rows of `df1`. So the expected output should look like below:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1] * 4, 'var4': ['P'] * 4, 'var2': list('abcd'), 'var3': range(4)})

   var1 var4 var2  var3
0     1    P    a     0
1     1    P    b     1
2     1    P    c     2
3     1    P    d     3
```

Is this possible to do without a manual replication of `df1` rows?

Comment: Strictly you want to join df1, df2 while broadcasting(/recycling) the contents of df1 to each row of df2. pandas doesn't directly support the boradcasting of the shorter df, so you have to do a slight hack

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `assign`

```
df2.assign(**df1.iloc[0].to_dict())
  var2  var3  var1 var4
0    a     0     1    P
1    b     1     1    P
2    c     2     1    P
3    d     3     1    P
```

Comment: Unfortunetely, if `df1` has multiple columns this becomes cumbersome. My bad, I should mention that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [`pd.DataFrame.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var2': list('abcd'), 'var3': range(4)})
>>> df3 = pd.concat((df2,df1), axis=1).ffill()
>>> df3
  var2  var3  var1
0    a     0   1.0
1    b     1   1.0
2    c     2   1.0
3    d     3   1.0
```

**EDIT**
This works for your edited question as well:

```
>>> df3 = pd.concat((df1,df2), axis=1).ffill()
>>> df3
   var1 var4 var2  var3
0   1.0    P    a     0
1   1.0    P    b     1
2   1.0    P    c     2
3   1.0    P    d     3
```

Comment: Only problem is this solution depends on index , if the df1 index is 100 , then the solution may off

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky tactic is to (manually) replicate the single-row `df1` to the needed shape...

```
pd.concat([df1] * df2.shape[0])

   var1 var4
0     1    P
0     1    P
0     1    P
0     1    P
```

...then concat it:

```
pd.concat([pd.concat([df1] * df2.shape[0], ignore_index=True), df2], axis=1)

   var1 var4 var2  var3
0     1    P    a     0
1     1    P    b     1
2     1    P    c     2
3     1    P    d     3
```